# How do I take my printed results from a webscape curl and turn them into selectable options? Bash

Tags: bash, shell

At the moment I want my bash script to print results from a webscape, and make them as selectable options. Later have the ability to download a pdf in a temp cache, and have zathura open it up.

```
    echo What newspaper are you looking for?
    read newspaper_input


#Replace spaces with pluses
newspaper_input="$(printf "%s" "${newspaper}" | tr " " "+")"

#The one command I can get to find everything 
scapemg=$(curl -s "https:///?cat=231&s=${newspaper}" | 
pup "header h2 a" | 
cut -d '"' -f2 | 
pup 'text{}' 
)
```

And when printing out the results of `$newspaper` it prints as follows

```
Linktowebpage The Washington Post – August 27, 2022 linktowebpage The Wall Street Journal – 27 August 2022 linktowebpage The Times – 27 August 2022 linktowebpage The Independent – 27 August 2022
```

I am trying to either print those links as options and or combine the titles with dates as links.

Cause what ever option is choosed then it gets pushed to the another variable as a link
All the links start off as https and end with .html

The next follows as to get the link from that webpage to download the pdf from

```
found_link=$(curl -s '${choiceoflink}' | 
pup 'a[target="_blank"]' | 
cut -d '"' -f4 |
grep 'https:*'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have better control if you separated each individual curl action (output control, failure control, etc).  The following script is a snippet to create a stream of lines, one per download request, which could then be fed to logic to perform the curl action.

```
#!/bin/sh

BASE=`basename "$0" ".sh" `
TMP="/tmp/tmp.$$.${BASE}"

newspaper="https://abc001.html The Washington Post – August 27, 2022 https://abc002.html The Wall Street Journal – 27 August 2022 https://abc003.html The Times – 27 August 2022 https://abc004.html The Independent – 27 August 2022"

echo "${newspaper}" | awk '{
    rem=$0 ;
    n=index( rem, " https://" )
    while( n != 0 ){
        beg=substr( rem, 1, n ) ;
        print beg ;
        rem=substr( rem, n+1 ) ;
        n=index( rem, " https://" )
    } ;
    print rem ;
}' | sed 's+\.html +\.html\|+'
```

Each line would need to be parsed to extract the URL from the descriptor.  That is easy enough with awk -F | .